# Optimization algorithm to solve the equation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have this equation `-0.19v+0.34x+0.13y+0.26z=26`. I need to find the minimum values of v, x, y, z that will give me a value of 26. I have a constraint that the lower bound value should be 0 and upper bound value should be 15 for all these parameters v, x, y and z. Please suggest me as to how to use the optimization algorithm in python to find the values.

Comment: look for integer linear programming  (ILP) solvers  (multiply all coefficients by 100)

Comment: The equation has no solution within those constraints. Set v=0 and x,y,z=15 to see why.